# Accessing a single dictionary in a list inside a json file

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have JSON file with the structure like this. This JSON file is the annotation data from my dataset, and I want to used for my YOLO object detection.

```py
{
    "description": "",
    "tags": [],
    "size": {
        "height": 720,
        "width": 1280
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": 768275656,
            "classId": 3753641,
            "description": "",
            "geometryType": "rectangle",
            "labelerLogin": "monochloride",
            "createdAt": "2021-07-20T00:50:24.512Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-07-20T00:50:24.512Z",
            "tags": [],
            "classTitle": "II",
            "points": {
                "exterior": [
                    [
                        383,
                        230
                    ],
                    [
                        659,
                        417
                    ]
                ],
                "interior": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is parsing the information from `"exterior"` in `"objects"` field, which contains the information of bounding box but I haven't succeeded in doing it.

Previously I tried to access the value using this code

```py
x1 = data['objects'][0]['points']['exterior'][0][0]
y1 = data['objects'][0]['points']['exterior'][0][1]
x2 = data['objects'][0]['points']['exterior'][1][0]
y2 = data['objects'][0]['points']['exterior'][1][1]
```

but the program throws

> `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Where did I do it wrong, and how to solve it?

Comment: include the code for how you loaded the json data.

Comment: What you've shown is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you were missing a opening curly brace, the following based on your code works just fine:

```
import json

# open json file
with open('yoloobject.json', 'r') as f:
    jsonstring = f.read()
    f.seek(0,0)
    data = json.load(f)


print('Json String: ', jsonstring)

x1 = data['objects'][0]['points']['exterior'][0][0]
y1 = data['objects'][0]['points']['exterior'][0][1]
x2 = data['objects'][0]['points']['exterior'][1][0]
y2 = data['objects'][0]['points']['exterior'][1][1]

print(f'bounding box: ({x1},{y2}), ({x2},{y2})')
```

with outputs:

```
Json String:  {
    "description": "",
    "tags": [],
    "size": {
        "height": 720,
        "width": 1280
    },
    "objects": [{
            "id": 768275656,
            "classId": 3753641,
            "description": "",
            "geometryType": "rectangle",
            "labelerLogin": "monochloride",
            "createdAt": "2021-07-20T00:50:24.512Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-07-20T00:50:24.512Z",
            "tags": [],
            "classTitle": "II",
            "points": {
                "exterior": [
                    [
                        383,
                        230
                    ],
                    [
                        659,
                        417
                    ]
                ],
                "interior": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
bounding box: (383,417), (659,417)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, after I checked back at my json file directory I found that another json file in that directory only has empty list in "objects" field because I forgot to give bounding box on the frame.